# HQL: Combine Left and Right Join

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, hql

Good day everyone,

I'm currently struggeling with converting the following SQL to HQL:

```
SELECT
  e.ID,
  p.ID,
  i.ID
FROM
  ENTRY e 
  JOIN PERSON p ON e.FK_PERSON = p.ID 
  RIGHT JOIN IDENTITY i ON i.FK_PERSON = p.ID
WHERE
  i.IS_MAIN_IDENTITY = 1
;
```

The way the DB is structured is:

- One person may have one or more identities
- One person has one main identity. The main identity is an identity with IS_MAIN_IDENTITY set to 1 (true)
- One person may have zero or more entries

The purpose of this query is to build a screen collection which should display all entries, their owner (person) and their main identity (because only the identity contains a persons name, etc.)

My attempt so far to perform this query in HQL was:

```
select 
    entr, 
    pers, 
    iden 
from 
    MEntry entr 
    join entr.entrPerson pers 
    right join iden.idenPerson
```

but this gave me the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node:
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
\-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'iden' {originalText=iden}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or is there a even better way to write this query?

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your SQL query like this:

```
SELECT
  e.ID,
  p.ID,
  i.ID
FROM
  PERSON p 
  INNER JOIN ENTRY e ON e.FK_PERSON = p.ID  
  INNER JOIN IDENTITY i ON i.FK_PERSON = p.ID
WHERE
  i.IS_MAIN_IDENTITY = 1
```

and the HQL equivalent is:

```
select 
    p 
from 
    Person p
    join fetch p.entries e
    join fetch p.identity
```

So you select only `Persons` but each Person also contains as `Identity` and a list of `Entry` entities. You can then access all the entries for each person on your UI.

Comment: That would be an idea of corse. But how would you then iterate over **all** Entries? It then sounds like I'd have to do an additional step to build a List of Entries out of that. Or did I miss something?

Comment: You just iterate over all persons and push all entries to a new collection